# Get All Hadoop Groups

Tags: hadoop, ldap, hdfs

I am looking for a way to fetch all Hadoop groups available on cluster.

Is there any way to do this using Java?

After doing some research i  found that cluster group mapping  depends on hadoop.security.group.mapping  property. It can  be configured as Shell or LDAP.

Irrespective of my configuration , i would to fetch all groups available either on shell/ldap

Any pointers for this?